# Quartz 2.2.3 TimeZone issue

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I want to schedule the cron job according to the specified time zone. It will fire fine for first time but next time it will not firing according to the specified time zone rather it is firing according to the system's time.

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withDescription(jobPojo.getDescription()).withIdentity(jobPojo.getTriggerName(), jobPojo.getTriggerGroup())
                        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(jobPojo.getExpression().trim()).inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(jobPojo.getTimeZone())).withMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires()).usingJobData(jobDataMap).forJob(jobKey).build();
```

// As i am passing timezone in json pojo eg: jobPojo.getTimeZone() ="GMT+4:00" which is Dubai timezone Id .  my system is running in India.
below is my fetching code :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Trigger trigger = scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey);
jobPojo.setNextFireTime(dateFormat.format(trigger.getNextFireTime()));
```

thanx in advance ..

Comment: Could you please provide some kind of an "HelloWorld" code?
Otherwise I see no way to help.
What is the purpose of the "fetching code"?

Comment: Using SimpleDateFormat#format without TimeZone, it converts to the formatted time with system timezone. What is your expectation?

Comment: Are you using Quartz's SimpleTrigger or CronTrigger? To specify timezone I believe you need to use the latter.